# AngularFire Authentication best practice

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am building an Angular Application using Firestore and Firebase Authentication. But I am struggling to find a great structure for the authentication process. Do you know some best practices or some public Github Repos I can take a look at?

I want to build an Application that works offline and so I would like to use a persistent Authentication. So when logging in I call: `this.afAuth.auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL).then(...)`.
The Login works fine, but I struggle with the pageload when he is already logged in. I tried some different `canActivate()` (AuthGuard) functions from StackOverflow and co. but it never worked out.
I tried the ugly way and looked for the authID in the local storage but this feels ugly and is not working properly with firestore.

I thought that it might work if I use service workers and start it offline and then check for connection and connect to firebase after the render. But I haven’t used Service workers nor the offline capabilities from firestore, so I am not sure if this would work out.

Can somebody give me some Ideas on how to approach this?

dependencies:

- angular 5
- angularfire 5.0 rc-4
- firebase 4.8

Comment: Can you provide more details on the issue with pageload?

Comment: sure, by "pageload" I meant when the user opens/reloads the website and is already Authenticated. So he logged in before and does not have to that every reload. For that, I use the persistence.LOCAL Attribute

Comment: So the thing is, Firebase Auth on page reload will reload the user to make sure is up to date and sometimes in the process will refresh the underlying ID token if it is expired. This helps invalidate sessions if a user is disabled, deleted, session revoked, etc. That is why there may be a slight delay there.

Comment: Is there any way to wrap this into a service worker or similar? I feels very non native to have that 1 second delay to check this every time an app is reloaded